# How to redirect to public in laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect, server, localhost

I upload my laravel project from localhost to server but to access the app my url is http://myhostexample.com/public/ I want it to be http://myhostexample.com I have modified the public/.htaccess  and here it is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: the docroot/webroot of the site should be pointing to the public folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .htaccess you shouldnot change anything;

you need to follow following steps to deploy the laravel project:

1. copy the files and folder of public folder in your laravel project and paste it on public_html
2. now open public_html and open to edit index.php file
3. now to change the path of autoload and bootstrap in index.php to where those file present
4. now check your domain

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```